# lm-sensors crazy?

Tags: temperature, sensors

My PC is new-built by me so I could mess it up probably...
however, sensors showing me many alarms I have no idea why.
do I have any problems?
very scared of this line

```
AUXTIN3:                +90.0°C    sensor = thermistor

nct6791-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:                  +0.39 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                    +1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:                   +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:                  +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:                    +1.03 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                    +2.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                    +0.91 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:                   +3.39 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:                   +3.17 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in9:                    +1.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                   +0.91 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                   +0.91 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                   +1.03 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                   +1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                   +0.46 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                  1072 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                  1084 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan6:                     0 RPM
SYSTIN:                 +31.0°C  (high = +98.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                 +30.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                +31.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:                +31.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                +31.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                +90.0°C    sensor = thermistor
PECI Agent 0:           +29.0°C  (high = +98.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)
                                 (crit = +100.0°C)
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C  
PCH_CPU_TEMP:            +0.0°C  
intrusion0:            OK
intrusion1:            ALARM
beep_enable:           disabled

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +30.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +30.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +29.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +26.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +27.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: AUXTIN3 I believe is from the power supply and from what I've read these sensors are often pretty flakey.  Is AUXTIN3 always 90.0 C? Is it highly variable?  Are the other AUXTIN temperatures pretty consistent?

Comment: The alarms are there because there's no proper min and max voltage available, for whatever reason. So the alarms themselves are nothing to worry about. Are you sure `nct6791-isa-0290` is the *exact* chipset on your motherboard, or maybe it's just a similar one? That could explain the missing min and max values.

Comment: I agree with the previous two comments but if I were you, I'd go check in the BIOS setup to validate the voltages as you could have power issues.  None of the reported voltages is above 4V which is weird.

Comment: @JuliePelletier checked. everything is fine. thanks for answers.